# showing jquery dialog on window beforeunload event

Tags: jquery, dialog, freeze

On window exit, I want to prompt users with a custom jquery dialog instead of standard browser alert and stop unload untill user reply to the questions in dialog. Pls let me know if this is do-able.

OR

Is there a way that I can launch a jquery dialog on window open and disable the parent window close button while the dialog is showing and enable when dialog closed by its own close button?

Would appreciate your valued feedback/solution

Answer (score 0):

In html page include bootboxjs js file and css file

```
      <div id="confirmation" class="dialog-confirm">
        <div id="dialogTitle" class="dialog-title">Confirmation!</div>
        <div id="dialogContainer" class="error_container" style="text-align: center">
            <p class="message bold">Do you want to close page?</p>
            <div style="text-align: right;">
                <input type="button" id="yes" value="Yes" class="input-button" /><input type="button" id="no"
                    value="No" class="input-button" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in js file

```
        $( window ).unload(function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
            $activeWindow = $(this);
            bootbox.confirm($('#dialog-confirm').find('#error_container').html(),
            function(result) {
            if (result == true) {
               $activeWindow.close();       
                }
            });
                      });
```